# PHP : Unable to access variable outside if block which is defined inside if block

Tags: php

Here in my PHP script test.php I am getting two types of values from python script using post request firstly I am getting signature value in PHP script and then I am creating a folder of that signature.

```
<?php

global $sign;

if (!empty($_POST['sign'])) {

    $sign = $_POST['sign'];
    if (!is_dir($sign)) {
        mkdir($sign);
    } else {
        echo "folder already exists";
    }
}

$target_path = "C:/wamp64/www/project/php/New Folder/$sign";
echo $sign;

echo $target_path;

if (!empty($_FILES['files'])) {
    $target = $target_path . '/' . basename($_FILES['files']['name']);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        echo "The file " . basename($_FILES['files']['name']) . " has been uploaded";
    } else {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
    
}
```

I want when I run this script a folder should be created all uploaded files should be copied in that folder. it creates folder successfully but not storing files in it.

Comment: are these on separate php files? maybe you can pass it by sessions or query strings

Comment: @Kevin these are on same php file

Comment: What is in `$_POST['sign']`?

Comment: @NigelRen It contains the username of pc which i retrieved using python and post to php

Comment: If the variable is not available outside the `if` afterwards, then the most logical conclusion is that the `if` block did not execute to begin with. Have you _verified_ that both the variables you are checking there with `isset`, are set at the same time?

Comment: The other possibility would be that you have a scope problem, because either of those two parts is wrapped into a function or something. (But we can’t determine that from what you have shown so far.)

Comment: @CBroe yes both variables are set at same time because when i change target path and run script it successfully creates folder and store files on specified location.

Comment: You are conditionally initialize `$sign` variable. If first `if` (`$_POST['sign']`) condition didn't pass, second `if` condition (`$_FILES['files']`) wouldn't have it available. You should put second if condition (`$_FILES['files']`) inside first if condition (`$_POST['sign']`) when you are sure you have that directory created.

Comment: @Tpojka I tried folder is successfully created but files are not storing

Comment: Debug it before each line (`var_dump(...$variables); exit;`) to check what you have before line execution fails. Also, warm recommendation for xdebug extension for debugging files.

Comment: @Tpojka i tried `var_dump(...$variables); exit;` it is showing nothing don't know why?

Comment: Not `$variables` but your expected ones like `$sign` or `$target_path`.

Comment: @Tpojka yeah i replaced $sign with $variables

Comment: Can you write and post (on github gist or pastebin) full part of code how it is looking now?

Comment: do I edit this question ?

Comment: Whatever is appropriate for you, just be sure you put code exactly how it is in your file to let us compare what is wrong.

Comment: I have edited the code kindly check

Comment: @Tpojka I have edited the code kindly check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234681/discussion-between-programmer-and-tpojka).